# Need help deploying a sinatra app to heroku using data mapper, no tables getting created

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, heroku-postgres

I am trying to deploy a small app on heroku. Deploying works fine, and it runs without a problem in my local environment. However, in production the app crashes immediately, throwing an "Application Error".

I suspect the problem is the fact that no database tables are getting created (when I look at the statistics on heroku/psql it says Tables: 0). I have no idea why though. The code is on github
https://github.com/valentin-zambelli/kanban-for-students/tree/master

Snapshot from my app.rb file

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'
require 'data_mapper'
require "date"
require "pg"

class Note
include DataMapper::Resource
property :id, Serial
property :content, Text, :required => true
property :status, Integer
property :created_at, DateTime
property :updated_at, DateTime
end

configure do
DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['postgres://coeastaxltnwlx:JnO2uo9HyracxQQ86n49u-FlzE@ec2-54-204-40-96.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d7n7n4iggsqnke'] || "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")
DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!
end
```

and from the gem file

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "2.1.2"

gem "sinatra"
gem "thin"
gem "haml"
gem 'data_mapper'
gem "pg"
gem "dm-postgres-adapter"
```

Here are the last few error messages I get from $ heroku logs

```
2014-10-27T10:55:48.591707+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2014-10-27T10:55:48.600652+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2014-10-27T10:55:55.697970+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET        path="/" host=murmuring-waters-2400.herokuapp.com request_id=1a3e9d90-c9f2-4cdc-842b-55d3152089ba     fwd="83.64.207.92" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2014-10-27T10:55:56.508412+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=murmuring-waters-2400.herokuapp.com request_id=d83bdf15-c09c-4919-ab05-30b862199323 fwd="83.64.207.92" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2014-10-27T10:56:06.872347+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=murmuring-waters-2400.herokuapp.com request_id=2e4a1984-c1ea-4234-8331-3f6a6f217137 fwd="54.161.222.26" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `DataMapper.setup` method call. You are looking up the database URL in the `ENV` object (collection of environment variables) which is good, but instead of passing the name of environment variable (`DATABASE_URL`) you have copied the actual URL into there. You should avoid putting this in your code.

Try something like:

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue! I created a constant called DATABASE_URL and used it in the method.